# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField myTable.test received a naive datetime

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

trying to send some records into my database. I am sending date in the following format:

> 2017-08-06 00:41:58

But receiving the message :

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField myTable.test received a naive datetime (2017-08-06 00:41:58) while time zone support is active.
```

Records are saving correctly ,but why am I see this message ?

My models:

```
class test(models.Model):       
    s_date = models.DateTimeField( verbose_name="Date" )
    s_value = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Value")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.s_date)+'-'+str(self.s_value)
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have added models to my post

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this issue when setting datetimes from strings (in unit tests). My solution was not to change the datetime/timezone code, but to change my datetime strings:

OLD: `2018-11-08 00:00:00` > RuntimeWarning

NEW: `2018-11-08 00:00:00+00:00` > No warning

I saw lots of questions related to RuntimeWarning but none addressed my particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting that error because in setting you have `USE_TZ = True` which actually means the timezone time is needed by the database

so in any place where you have used `datetime` of python change it to `django timezone time`

example

```
from django.utils import timezone

time = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now())
```

Comment: I suppose you meant this `timezone.now` instead of this `timezone.now()`

Comment: now is a function, so if you want to get the output you need now(),

Comment: yep that's true but if you want to pass it as default or these then you would use `timezone.now`

Comment: both works properly if passed inside  a model field, to be sure i am already using now() in model :)

Comment: you have to tell us more what and where you are using it??